# NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification with numerous core data stores

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have 2 separate data stores in my app, both of which go onto a background thread at the same time. I therefore have this code to set it up:

```
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self.dataStoreManager
                           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                             object:nil];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *dataStoreBackgroundPSC = self.dataStoreManager.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;

    [notificationCenter addObserver:[AppDelegate applicationDelegate].coreDataManager
                           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                             object:nil];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *journalDataPSC = [AppDelegate applicationDelegate].coreDataManager.persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Will this cause problems, as both objects will receive the notification, or will they treat it in a way that won't negatively impact either data store?

EDIT:
Ok, it turns out this is, in fact, not good. Alternatives? If i don't save one of them on the background thread, does it still need that notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are looking at the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` from the different `NSManagedObjectContext`s associated with each `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

Specify those as the `object:` parameter instead of `nil` in your calls to `addObserver`.